# Cursor Pagination not working for my Reviews page

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I'm looking for help in infinite scrolling cursor pagination using `relaystylePagination` in Apollo GraphQL. I've been pondering about this for the past two days to no avail. Here's the code for my application. By the way it works for my other components using the `typePolicies` Query and Repository.

// apolloClient.js

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        repositories: relayStylePagination(),
      },
    },
    Repository: {
      fields: {
        reviews: relayStylePagination(),
      },
    },
    Me: {
      fields: {
        reviews: relayStylePagination(),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

// Component

```
const Reviews = () => {
  const variables = {
    includeReviews: true,
    first: 1,
  };

  const { data, error, loading, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_USER, {
    variables,
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Text>Loading reviews...</Text>;
  }

  const currentUser = data.me;

  const reviews = currentUser
    ? currentUser.reviews.edges.map((edge) => edge.node)
    : [];

  const handleFetchMore = () => {
    const canFetchMore = !loading && data?.me.reviews.pageInfo.hasNextPage;

    if (!canFetchMore) {
      return;
    }

    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        after: data.me.reviews.pageInfo.endCursor,
        ...variables,
      },
    });
  };

  const onEndReached = () => {
    handleFetchMore();
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={reviews}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <ReviewItem review={item} refetch={refetch} />}
      keyExtractor={({ id }) => id}
      onEndReached={onEndReached}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    />
  );
};
```

// Apollo GraphQL Query

```
export const GET_USER = gql`
  query getCurrentUser(
    $includeReviews: Boolean = false
    $first: Int
    $after: String
  ) {
    me {
      id
      username
      reviews(first: $first, after: $after) @include(if: $includeReviews) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            createdAt
            text
            repository {
              id
              fullName
            }
            rating
          }
          cursor
        }
        pageInfo {
          startCursor
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```